# Understanding GTFS static data relationships?

Tags: model, general-transit-feed-specification

I'm trying to build a data store for the GFTS static data, but can't get my head around the relationships between Route, Stop, Stop_Times and Trips.

e.g.
Route 2E runs between airport and city centre.
It has a fixed number of stops on this route.
An instance of the 2E is a trip which leaves the airport at a certain time (9:30) to travel to the city.  Its Stop times are the times that this trip specifically will be at designated stops.

However, this implies a link between Route and Stops.  Route 2E has 12 stops between Airport and city.  This never changes regardless of whether you catch the 9:30 trip or 11:30 trip.

So Stop Times are linked to Trip.  But stops should linked to Routes.  But every data model I have seen does not show the route stop relationship.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The same Routes can have different stops, depending on the trip. For example, the trip A goes from airport to city, and trip B goes from airport, to shopping center, then to city. The route's trips have most of the same stops, but some of the trips may have more or less than other ones. It makes more sense to link stop to trip because that is the determination whether a bus stops there or not.

the stops may have all the trips of a route stop there such as the airport, but a stop may have a few trips of a route stop there such as the shopping center.

Answer (score 0):

The `trip.txt` file has a `trip_id` field in it. The `stop_times.txt` forms the relation because it also has a `trip_id` field in addition to a `stop_id` field, which links it to the `stops.txt` file.

Finally, the `trips.txt` also has the `route_id` field and this is how it links to the `routes.txt` file. A route can be made of many trips.

Answer (score 0):

`Routes.txt` file provides route names serviced by carrier.

`Stops.txt` file provides stops and corresponding geographic coordinates serviced by a carrier.

`Trips.txt` file provides all the trips serviced under a route, depending on service_type(e.g. special day, holiday) and it also holds geographical shape id information using which you can render the trip.

`Stop_times` file provides the trip timings associated with the stop.